# form validation with javascript - event.target.form.classList is undefined - css tricks tutorial

Tags: javascript, undefined, typeerror, blur, formvalidation.io

So, I have been following along a Tutorial from CSS-Tricks about Form Validation.

( https://css-tricks.com/form-validation-part-2-constraint-validation-api-javascript/ )

This is the code I copy pasted from that website.
Why do I get that error message in the console saying **"TypeError: event.target.form.classList is undefined."?**

And what do I have to add and write to make that event defined. I'm a beginner, and I can imagine, that the answer must be simple.

Here is the code so far:

```
<body>
  <form action="form_process.php" method="post" class="validate">
    <label>Enter Name here:
      <input type="text" name="naaame" value="" required></input>
    </label>
    <label>Enter E-Mail here:
      <input type="email" name="email" value="" required></input>
    </label>
    <label>Enter Number here:
      <input type="number" name="number" value="" required></input>
    </label>
    <label>Enter Date here:
      <input type="date" name="date" value="" required></input>
    </label>
    <button type="submit">Send form</button>
  </form>

  <!-- Scripts from broiler plate not from tutorial -->

  <script src="js/vendor/modernizr-3.8.0.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/vendor/modernizr-custom.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script>
    window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/vendor/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"><\/script>')
  </script>
  <script src="js/plugins.js"></script>
  <script src="js/main.js"></script>

<!-- Scripts from Tutorial -->
<script>
 var forms = document.querySelectorAll('.validate');
 for (var i = 0; i < forms.length; i++) {
      forms[i].setAttribute('novalidate', true);
 }

 // Listen to all blur events
 document.addEventListener('blur', function (event) {

    // Only run if the field is in a form to be validated
    if (!event.target.classList.contains('validate')) return;

    // Validate the field
    var error = event.target.validity;
    console.log(error);

 }, true);
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You registered a blur event on all the document so you have to expect this type of error

you have to check if target is not null so change

```js
if (!event.target.classList.contains('validate')) return;
```

to

```js
if (event.target && !event.target.classList.contains('validate')) return;
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response! :-)

I tried it and it removed that TypeError message.
However, now the part at the end with 

`console.log(error);`

doesn't work. I think it is supposed to show me an error in the console, right? 

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

So, for everyone that has read my question.
I found another way, which didn't solve my issue.
But I found another **form validation polyfill javascript library** which did work till browser IE 9.

I now am using this one: https://github.com/cferdinandi/bouncer